# How can I convert unsafe characters to safe characters for XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml, escaping

I have Finnish characters in my text (for example ä, ö and å) that are unsafe in XML, is there any library/framework for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think I'd really call these characters "unsafe". The character encoding has to be correct and match the XML declaration, that's all.

Comment: Apparently my servlet response didn't have response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); but when I added it, everything worked fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML supports Unicode, so the only thing you really need to escape are the five basic XML entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos). If you use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML, it will turn all your ä, ö and å into ugly \uabcd stuff.

Comment: Incidentally, there are some characters that the XML spec treats as illegal, no matter how you try to encode them.  The ASCII NUL character for example.

Answer (score 2):

So the best method to ecsape strings for xml is StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML
from Commons Lang, but as someone here already said it is not enough 
E.g. there are some non-printable control chars which should be removed from string if one wants to have valid xml.
To do this I use this snippet:

```
/**
 * Function to strip control characters from a string.
 * Any character below a space will be stripped from the string.
 * @param iString the input string to be stripped.
 * @return a string containing the characters from iString minus any control characters.
 */
public String stripControlChars(String iString) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(iString);
    int idx = result.length();
    while (idx-- > 0) {
        if (result.charAt(idx) < 0x20 && result.charAt(idx) != 0x9 && 
                result.charAt(idx) != 0xA && result.charAt(idx) != 0xD) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("deleted character at: "+idx);
            }
            result.deleteCharAt(idx);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

// Then 
String s = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(stripControlChars(s));
```

Also it is important to use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML Commons Lang version 3 as previous versions of that method where escaping more then needed.

Answer (score 1):

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has the [escapeXML](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml(java.lang.String)) method which will suit your needs.